# Exclusion constraint on recursive foreign key (on the example of a Tree)

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, constraint, recursive, tree

I have the table with recursive foreign key. It's just hierarchical tree structure:

```
CREATE TABLE tree (
    id              INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    value           INTEGER NOT NULL,
    tree_id         SMALLINT NOT NULL CHECK (tree_id > CAST(0 AS SMALLINT)),
    parent_id       INTEGER REFERENCES tree ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,

    EXCLUDE (tree_id WITH =) WHERE (parent_id IS NULL) -- allow only one root within tree
);
```

How to reject inserting records with non-null `parent_id` and different `tree_id`? I.e. foreign key `parent_id` can have reference only to primary key `id` within the same `tree_id`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a composite foreign key:

```
(tree_id, parent_id) REFERENCES (tree_id, id)
```

You will need to first change the PK or add a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(tree_id, id)`